# add + 1 to <input> value for each click event. increment stops at number 3 Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, html

by default my input value is `1`, i want to add +1 each time i click my `button`. it stops adding when when it reaches `20`.

i cant figure out why my code stops at number `3` and just repeats `3`.

[image]

**this is my HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" id="total" value="20" /> //total num
<input type="hidden" id="cur_num" value="1" /> //current num
<button type="button" id="add" >Add</button>
```

this is javascript and demo here http://jsfiddle.net/zXpen/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", "#add", function() {

        cur = $('#cur_num').val();
        total = $('#total').val();
        console.log(cur);

        if (cur <= total) {
            cur = parseInt(cur)+parseInt(1);
            $('#cur_num').val(cur);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: see: http://jsfiddle.net/zXpen/2/ (you have to convert cur and total to int in order to be able to compare them (cur <= total) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.val()` returns a string, so `cur <= total` is comparing two strings lexicographically, i.e. characters at each position are compared against each other. And `"2"` in `"20"` is smaller than `"3"` in `"3"`.

You have to convert the values to numbers before you compare them, not after that, e.g. by using the unary plus operator. Also don't forget to declare your variables with `var`:

```
var cur = +$('#cur_num').val();
var total = +$('#total').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your values to integers:

```
cur = parseInt($('#cur_num').val());
total = parseInt($('#total').val());
```

At the moment your code is comparing "2" <= "20", then "3" <= "20" (as strings). Therefore the if condition is not met and the code within it is not run.

Also, you don't need `parseInt(1)`. `cur = parseInt(cur)+1;` is fine.